# Reload Javascript Gage Only, not the Whole Page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, raphael, justgage

I have a Javascript Gage that displays a percent and refreshed every 5 seconds in an ASPX page. As of now I am refreshing the whole page. How can I refresh just the Javascript Gage? Refreshing the whole page is not good practice. The Gage is inside div gg11. I am new at javascript, how can I achieved this?

ASPX

```
 <div id="gg11" class="gauge"></div>
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=http://localhost:63738/main.aspx">
```

ASPX.cs

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {         
        JavaScriptMethod();           
    }

    protected void JavaScriptMethod()
    {
        Calculations();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.Append("<script>");
        sb.Append("var gg1 = new JustGage({");
        sb.Append("id: \"gg11\",");
        sb.Append("donut: 0,");
        sb.Append("title: \"LAKE WALES\",");
        sb.Append("titleFontColor: \"#000000\",");           
        sb.AppendFormat("value: {0},", percent);
        sb.Append("min: 0,");
        sb.Append("max: 100,");
        sb.Append("labelFontColor: \"#000000\",");
        sb.Append("humanFriendlyDecimal: 1,");
        sb.Append("decimals: 1,");
        sb.Append("symbol: \"%\",");
        sb.Append("startAnimationType : \"bounce\",");
        sb.Append("refreshAnimationType: \"bounce\",");
        sb.Append("startAnimationTime: 1000,");
        sb.Append("gaugeWidthScale: 1.2,");
        sb.Append("customSectors: [{color: \"#ff0000\",lo: 0,hi: 79}, {color: \"#ffa500\",lo: 80,hi: 89}, {color: \"#1eae1e\",lo: 90,hi: 100}],");
        sb.Append("counter: true");
        sb.Append("});");
        sb.Append("</script>");

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "temp", sb.ToString(), false);
    }
```

Comment: Try to use ajax. There plenty ways to use it, some jquery, pagemethods.

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of JavaScript, jQuery and ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods, like this:

Markup:

```
<div id="gg11" class="gauge"></div>
```

---

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(doAjax, 5000);
});

function doAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "YourPageName.aspx/GetGage",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result) {
            if (result.hasOwnProperty("d")) {
                // The .d is part of the result so reference it
                //  to get to the actual JSON data of interest
                // Put result into DIV
                $('#gg11').html(result.d);
            }
            else {
                // No .d; so just use result
                // Put result into DIV
                $('#gg11').html(result);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

> Note: You will need to change the name of `YourPageName.aspx` to the name of your .aspx page. Also, the `.d` syntax was an anti-XSS protection put in by Microsoft in the ASP.NET 3.5 release of ASP.NET AJAX; therefore the check to see if the .d property is there or not.

---

Code-behind:

```
[WebMethod]
 public static string GetGage()
 {
     Calculations();
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

     sb.Append("<script>");
     sb.Append("var gg1 = new JustGage({");
     sb.Append("id: \"gg11\",");
     sb.Append("donut: 0,");
     sb.Append("title: \"LAKE WALES\",");
     sb.Append("titleFontColor: \"#000000\",");           
     sb.AppendFormat("value: {0},", percent);
     sb.Append("min: 0,");
     sb.Append("max: 100,");
     sb.Append("labelFontColor: \"#000000\",");
     sb.Append("humanFriendlyDecimal: 1,");
     sb.Append("decimals: 1,");
     sb.Append("symbol: \"%\",");
     sb.Append("startAnimationType : \"bounce\",");
     sb.Append("refreshAnimationType: \"bounce\",");
     sb.Append("startAnimationTime: 1000,");
     sb.Append("gaugeWidthScale: 1.2,");
     sb.Append("customSectors: [{color: \"#ff0000\",lo: 0,hi: 79}, {color: \"#ffa500\",lo: 80,hi: 89}, {color: \"#1eae1e\",lo: 90,hi: 100}],");
     sb.Append("counter: true");
     sb.Append("});");
     sb.Append("</script>");

     return sb.ToString();
 }
```

Comment: Almost there. This makes the Gage show up and then goes away. Any idea was causing this?

Comment: @Apollo - does it go away in less than 5 seconds of it appearing?

Comment: @Apollo - did you remove the `<meta>` tag refresh from the page?

Comment: Just removed the meta tag and that fix the problem. But now my gridviews in the update panels are not refreshing.

Comment: This is a bad mix, `UpdatePanels`, meta tag refresh and JavaScript `setInterval()`. Is the JavaScript gauge value tied to the updating of the grid views? In other words, is the gauge value showing a percentage of the grid view or is the percentage value related to something else?

Comment: No it gets the gage value from the Calculations method which is a query.

Answer (score 0):

Use the javascript [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) method to make an ajax call to your server where your sever page returns the HTML markup for the specific part you are interested in. Remove the meta tag which refreshes the whole page.

Assuming you have jQuery loaded in your page

```
$(function(){

  var intId= setInterval(function(){ 
                         $("#gg11").load("getgauge.aspx");}, 5000); 

});
```

This will keep sending an ajax request to the server page every 5 seconds!
You should have the getgauge.aspx returns the HTML markup you want to show in the UI.

If you are interested in only the changed value (whenever some value is changed in server), You may look into libraries like SignalR which makes realtime communication an easy task.

Comment: where do you get getgauge.aspx from? My div is located in Main.aspx, I put that there and it just duplicates the whole page.

Comment: That is a new page which is used to server only the partial page markup (For your gauge). You may use an ashx handler as well for returning this markup instead of an aspx file.